# Logistic regression and bag of words

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, statistics, data-science

From what I understood X[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yezr7.png) would be the occurrence of a word while beta[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yezr7.png) would be a weight of that word. My question is regarding how is the weight calculated? based on what?

Comment: Maybe you should have cited a link to your question or check out some other related forum... https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit difficulty, because i don't know what exactly you want to do. But in general you have data providing you the Xs. And an outcome. The outcome should be bernoulli distributed. That means only two outcomes are possible. Now you calculate a probability from your Xs. For example you want to know if a text is about Tom Hanks. And your x1 is 1 if the word "Tom" is in the text. X can also describe how often "Tom" appears in the text. You try to select a beta so that the [sogmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function from beta1*x1 returns the right probalility that the text is about "Tom Hanks". If the word "Tom" is present in the text. To calculate beta normaly some machine learning algorithm is used, such as a gradient descent. I simplified it a little bit to get the idea. I think [this](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/5.pdf) explains it quite good. In the end you get a model from your data which predicts a outcome on new data, where you only know the Xs.

Comment: I’m trying to do a fake news classifier, but I’m still learning and wanted to know how it works since I could not find anything that really explains it but the document you told me to read, explained it really good.